# Looping Raphael animation without fps issues?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Im just experimenting with Raphaels javascript and got this little bit of code:

```
window.onload = function (){
buildAnimation();
}

var buildAnimation = function () {
    var p = Raphael(50,50,1050,1050);
    p.rect(50,50,1050,1050).attr({fill : "white",stroke : "none"});
    p.rect(50,50,150,150).animate({fill: "#FF5555", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 80, "stroke-opacity": 0.5}, 2000);
}
```

If i add , buildAnimation after the .animate after about 3 loops i get really bad fps issues and it eventually slows and crashes.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but one possible solution would be using callbacks (somehow native svg animation looping feels more intuitive, but not sure if there is any animation looping in Raphael).

Not quite sure if you are calling buildAnimation multiple times, but it feels like any building of the raphael elements should be done in one function, then just calling the animation from another function would be better. Try to avoid any repeated creation of elements.

```
var p = Raphael(50,50,1050,1050);
var myRect = p.rect(50,50,100,100).attr({fill : "white",stroke : "none"});

var anim = Raphael.animation({fill: "#FF5555", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 80, "stroke-opacity": 0.5}, 2000, 'linear', animEnd );
var animFinish = Raphael.animation({ fill: "white", stroke: "none", 'stroke-width': 1 }, 'linear', animStart );

function animEnd () {
    myRect.animate( animFinish );
};

function animStart () {
    myRect.animate( anim );
}

animStart();
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/k8tX7/2/